# Windows Phone - Link doesn't open properly from mail

Tags: html, windows-phone, gmail, freemarker

I have really weird issue.
I'm sending a user really long link to user (> 30 chars) but unfortunetly it doesn't open properly on Windows Phone - e.g I have link `www.test.com/test/{20 chars}` and If I click on it, it does open in new tab but it only goes to `www.test.com`. If I hold on link and manually click to open in new tab it does open properly. What's strange is that it only happens on Windows Phone (android, ios, PC OSes work fine). Link is like this:

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/test/test/{hash}" target="_blank">Open link</a>
```

Might be worth to mention that this is GMAIL.

I couldn't find an answer but I'm pretty sure there's way to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it can be issue of escape characters. Try to convert url to escaped url.